# Validating attempt on NFA to Regular Expression

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

So i tried turning the following NFA into a GNFA (first attempt).

Please don't ask why i chose to do such a complex NFA on my first try, i just like the challenge i guess?

ab is the concatenation of a and b, the language consists of a, b and c.

$L = \{a, b, c\}$

[image]

I calculated the following to be the Regular Expression of the NFA:

$b^{+}c$ $\cup$ $(((a$ $\cup$ $b^{+}ab)\cup(b^{+}c(b$ $\cup$ $cb^{*}c)))(a$ $\cup$ $cb^{*}ab)^{*}(b$ $\cup$ $cb^{*}c))$

Comment: So what's your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your exercise problem.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.